# Question about MySQL Database and using .complete

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a project with a mysql database and am having trouble finding some documentation on a particular function. Can someone help me?

This is my get request for instance. Can someone help me understand the .complete?

```
messages: {
    get: function (req, res) {
      //use orm
      Message.findAll({ include: [User] })
        .complete(function(err, results) {
          //todo: handle err
          res.json(results);
        });
```

Comment: An ORM like [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/v5/) uses Promises and is compatible with `async`/`await`. You should learn that model instead of the old-school `complete()` chaining. Callback functions get extraordinarily complex in a hurry.

Comment: agreed. In this assignment they want us to use callbacks and next we will be using promises. I'm just wondering what the .complete part does because I was unable to find documentation on it.

Comment: You're going to have to specify which ORM you're using because there's a lot of them.

Comment: The orm is sequelize.

Comment: I don't think Sequelize has had a `complete()` method for a long time, perhaps even Sequelize v2 or earlier. It's now on version 5 and since at least version 3 it's been using Promises, so `.then(...).catch(err ...)` to chain on.

Comment: That's good info, I'm going to use .then then. (pun intended) And also .spread in my post.